# Sync apps and settings between Windows 8 and Windows 10 PC

Tags: windows, windows-8, sync, windows-10-preview

I'm kinda interested in testing Microsoft's upcoming version of Windows namely **Windows 10** on my PC. 
But before I'm going to test it I need to be sure whether it will work or not.

I already have Windows 8 installed in my laptop. Will my PC keep syncing after installing Windows 10 with my laptop (Win8 installed) if I sign in with my Microsoft account?

It should do that, but I didn't find any official source yet.

Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: Please, go try it first, and come back with [actual questions about actual problems](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask). Share your research.

Comment: it works fine. I've installed the Preview in a VM and got all my settings/apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now installed Windows 10 in my PC and it synced all my apps and settings from previous version of Windows. So the sync is working well.

Thanks to Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 for encouragement and magicandre1981 for the confirmation.